# View Model function name issue in js related code

Tags: javascript, oop, knockout.js

I am not familiar with oops implementation in js specific code.
I saw this code

```
var RandomNumberGameViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            Level = function (id, identifier) {
                return {
                    id: ko.observable(id),
                    identifier: ko.observable(identifier)
                };
            }

            self.GenerateRandomNumber = function () {
                var number = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < self.digitsLimit() ; i++) {
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * self.digitsLimit()) + 1);
                    number += randomNumber;
                }
                return number;
            }
        }
```

1. What will be called `RandomNumberGameViewModel()` is it a name of any function?
2. I guess `Level()` is a function name then what is `GenerateRandomNumber()`? If both are functions then why is one **pre-fixed with self keyword** and the other is not?

Please explain the code which I highlighted here.

Thanks

Comment: tbh that's not a very good example of a knockout view model. If you want to learn how this code works look at knockouts interactive tutorials. http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: i am not after knockout rather i am after coding pattern. i like to know why one method is prefix with self and another is not prefix with self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, `Level` *should* be preceded by either `var` or `self.`. I don't know what the author intended, but there are two possibilities, as I see it:

1. `Level` is supposed to be a private function inside `RandomNumberGameViewModel`, and therefore should read `var Level = ...`.
2. `Level` is supposed to be a public function on the `RandomNumberGameViewModel` "class", and should therefore read `self.Level = ...`.

As is discussed here, you should never omit `var` for variables:
[What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript)

If you are interested in learning more about OOP in JavaScript (and other useful patterns), you should read http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ which I think explains things pretty well.

Comment: so u mean to say Level is private function that is why it is not prefix with self.Level. am i understood properly?